# What is the mean absolute difference between values in a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, standard-deviation

I understand that variance is mean of squared differences and that standard deviation is square root of the mean.

What, however, is the average difference between values in a normal distribution (without considering the sign, of course, since if we consider the sign, it would be 0)?

Comment: In my opinion, it is still zero. Case of very large mean, the absolute value transform is not material and the expected difference remains zero. Instead, consider moving the mean to zero. This implies we have a Truncated Normal distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20and%20statistics%2C%20the,applications%20in%20statistics%20and%20econometrics.) which is truncated at the mean (now zero). As this, per Wikipedia, is "a mean preserving contraction" again no effect, the answer remains zero.

Comment: @AJKOER …what? I think you've probably misread the question (and also the Wikipedia article you reference). In particular, you seem to be considering the *difference of the absolute values* of two i.i.d. normal random variables, whereas the OP is clearly asking about their [*absolute difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_difference) (i.e. $|X-Y|$, not $|X|-|Y|$). Also, as Wikipedia clearly says, "truncation is a mean-preserving contraction *combined with a mean-changing rigid shift*" (*emphasis* mine), and thus is not mean-preserving as a whole.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assume that $X, Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are iid.

Then their difference is $X-Y\sim N(0,2\sigma^2)$. As you write, the expectation of this difference is zero.

And the *absolute value of this difference* $|X-Y|$ follows a [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution). Its mean can be found by plugging the mean $0$ and variance $2\sigma^2$ of $X-Y$ into the formula at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution):

$$ \sqrt{2}\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} = \frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}. $$

A quick simulation in R is consistent with this:

```
> nn <- 1e6
> sigma <- 2
> set.seed(1)
> XX <- rnorm(nn,0,sigma)
> YY <- rnorm(nn,0,sigma)
> mean(abs(XX-YY))
[1] 2.257667
> sqrt(2)*sigma*sqrt(2/pi)
[1] 2.256758
```

Comment: Is there an **immense gratitude** button anywhere on the internet?

Comment: Yes, it's the little checkmark you already clicked - thank you!

Comment: Thank you Stephan, very grateful!!  Just a small question: which formula are you referring to on the Wikipedia page? Please pardon my less understanding and ability. If you could provide a link to the formula image, it would be very helpful.

Comment: It's the formula for the mean "$\mu_Y$" in the sidebar at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution), where we substitute $\mu=0$ for the mean of $X-Y$ and use $\sqrt{2}\sigma$ in the place of $\sigma$ for the standard deviation of $X-Y$.

Comment: Thank you Stephan!!

Comment: Stephan, could you please explain why do we need to take the variance of $X-Y$ as $2\sigma^2$?

Comment: This is a general result on [sums of independent normal variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Operations_on_normal_deviates): if $X\sim N(\mu_X, \sigma^2_X)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma^2_Y)$ are independent, then $-Y\sim N(-\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$ and $X-Y=X+(-Y)\sim N(\mu_X-\mu_Y, \sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)$.

Comment: @RiteshSingh You can start a bounty for the question, then assign it to Stephan Kolassa if you want.

Comment: Stephan, I have sent you an email. Please do check it out if / when free.

Comment: Dear Stephan, Your answer helped me in my work, and I have gratefully acknowledged your help in my paper: [Paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10509-021-04006-5), [Full Text](https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s10509-021-04006-5?sharing_token=KcBlr7cAF11g6aEoa2S83_e4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY5NWqJKRyY9HMYNiOh-pLQKcuROMipcdEHV_V-EHzsD8rqvbVYA_0ZWzYJcfqbZBq3aJF5H7inBGJ28VO_5GwIMJQX5S88REzof8zYy4c6f6044DC1dV3axhe8t5qM2XtA%3D)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a very nice gesture on your part!